# Why is the output from this regulator not a constant DC?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I have built a link switch.

The output is DC 5V but, when measured with an oscilloscope, itis not constant.

Why does this happen?

How do I get constant  DC   output?

Any design problem?

[image]

[datasheet link switch](https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/product_document/data_sheet/linkswitch-tn_family_datasheet.pdf)

Output voltage:

Output wave form much noisy ..so i will updated soon

Comment: To answer this question, you need to show the load (it requires a load for stability) and the PCB layout. Show where you have the probes attached on the oscilloscope, that can make a huge difference.

Comment: @VoltageSpike i am create this circuit   in general purpose PCB (similar to circuit diagram)

Comment: Also, please show your probe setup. Dave at EEVblog made a video about how important a good probe technique is for output ripple measurements.

Comment: Are you using a mains-frequency isolation transformer for this non-isolated circuit? Unless you're using that or an isolated probe or internally isolated oscilloscope with high CMRR there's a lot of potential (pun intended) for problems.

Comment: You need to answer the questions asked to you if you want a answer.

Comment: @winnyAre you using a mains-frequency isolation transformer for this non-isolated circuit?   ANS: NO transformer use,the output of link switch directly applied to load.

Answer (score 4):

The LNK302 datasheet that you linked recommends that you change R4 to 2.4Kohms or less if the circuit has zero load.

[image]

[image]

Comment: same issue still exist